# How to make integer value auto-increment in java?

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I have a text file which has records like this:

```
1 Hamada PEPSI
2 Johny PEPSI
```

the format of these records is like this:

```
int id, String name, String drink
```

I wrote a small method to add records to this text file but id must be unique for every record

for example:
these records are not acceptable:

```
1 Hamada PEPSI
2 Johny PEPSI
1 Terry Milk
```

here is my code:

```
public void addProduct(int id, String name, String drink)
{
Formatter x = null;
try{
FileWriter f = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\products.txt", true);
x = new Formatter(f);
x.format("%d %s %s %s%n",id,name,drink);
x.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println("NO Database");
}
}
```

How to make id be auto-increment when entering new record?

for example:

```
1 Ahmed PEPSI
2 Hamada PEPSI
3 Johny Milk
4 Terry Milk
5 Jack Miranda
6 Sarah Juice
```

Comment: Add a static variable that is written when you add a product and increment it as soon as you write the record.  You can't reclaim deleted indexes.

Comment: With a little thought to the design, this question becomes trivial.  Create a class that represents your serialized data file.  That class will have all methods required for reading the file, writing to the file, retrieving records, yada yada.  It will also store metadata on the state of the file, like the next id number.  Just increment each time you add a record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found an answer for my question, hope this be useful for other programmers.

this is the code:

```
public void addProduct(String name, String drink)
{ 
int max = 0;
Scanner y = null;
try{
y = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\products.txt"));
while(y.hasNext())
{
int a = y.nextInt(); // id
String b = y.next(); // name
String c = y.next(); // drink
max = a;
}
y.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
Formatter x = null;
try{
FileWriter f = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\products.txt", true);
x = new Formatter(f);
x.format("%d %s %s%n",++max,name,drink);
x.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Explanation: we create a variable called max and initialize it to zero .. well ... now if it was the first time to create file and adding records to it, first id will be 1 for the first record...

if text file is already exists... then the program will search for max id and increment it .... for example:

```
  1 Hamada PEPSI
  2 Johny MILK
```

then when adding new record it will have the id = 3

if there is any errors, please tell me guys :)

thanks to all of you :)

Comment: @duffymo please check this solution and thanks for your help bro :)

Comment: [You should format your code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style)

Answer (score 2):

Ugly code.  You're a beginner, so you need to know that readability matters.  Pay attention to format.

Don't print message to System.out.  Always print a stack trace at minimum in a catch block.

```
private static int AUTO_INCREMENT_ID = 1;

public void addProduct(String name, String drink) {
    Formatter x = null;
    try {
        FileWriter f = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\products.txt", true);
        x = new Formatter(f);
        x.format("%d %s %s %s%n",AUTO_INCREMENT_ID++,name,drink);
        x.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

More bad code: Can't change file; don't close resources.

Comment: +1, for basic guidelines for beginner.One note to mention, you are calling instance method which modifies static variable, I think AtomicInteger should be used instead.

Comment: Good suggestion re: AtomicInteger.  Might be over noob's head.  I might prefer adding synchronized to this method so other bad things don't happen.  Simultaneous access and modification of file will be a bigger problem.

Comment: this code is not working, id is not incremented each time i add new record. it keeps adding 1 for every record as id

Comment: You wanted a new id for every new record.  This will do it.  If you want database features, you ought to use a database.  Spell your requirements out better and I can easily improve on it.   Not worth more effort by me.

Comment: no i just test this code and not do that, every time add 1 as id for each record

Comment: no database features it just adding them to text file

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Before you begin you need to read the file and find the max id that appears, then increment that.  Point is that you should either be smarter about what you pass in for id or prohibit users from creating bad ones.  Go make it so.